# Should I iterate a Java collection to get a subset, or should I convert it to array first then iterate to get it?

Tags: java, performance, collections, iteration

I am calling an API which returns me a collection of objects. I want to get a subset of the objects. There are two solutions that I am thinking. Which one would give me better performance? Based on my understanding, the `toArray()` call mainly will iterate through the collection once. If that's true, then the solution one would be better?

Solution 1 -

```
public static List<String> get(UUID recordid, int start, int count) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    ...

    Collection<String> columnnames = result.getColumnNames();
    int index = 0; 
    for (UUID columnname : columnnames) {
        if ((index >= start) && (index - start < count)) {
            names.add(columnname);
        }
        index++;
    }

    return names;
}
```

Solution 2 -

```
public static List<String> get(UUID recordid, int start, int count) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    ...

    Collection<String> columnnames = result.getColumnNames();
    String[] nameArray = columnnames.toArray(new String(columnnames.size()));

    for (int index = 0; index < nameArray.length && count > 0; index++, count--) {
        names.add(nameArray[index]);
    }

    return names;
}
```

Comment: it sounds like he is receiving a `Collection` not necessarily a `List`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely, iterating through a collection is better than converting it an array first, and then iterating through the array.

The second approach provides with extra time and memory expenses:

1. Allocation memory for an array
2. Filling the array with contents of the collection

Answer (score 20):

If your Collection is a List, you can use the `subList(fromIndex, toIndex)` method.

Example:

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> y = x.subList(5, 10);
```

Comment: We don't know that it's a `List` -- only a `Collection`, I think?

Answer (score 2):

I think the subList answer is the way to go.

```
public static List<String> get(UUID recordid, int start, int count) {
    Collection<String> columnnames = result.getColumnNames();
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(columnnames);
    return names.subList(start, start+count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list, use the subList method. Here's an example of doing so:

```
private static void doTestListBreak()
{
    for (int i=0; i<= 300; i++)
    {
        for (int delta=1; delta<= 30; delta++)
        {
            testListBreak(i, delta);
        }
    }
}

public static void testListBreak(int numItems, int delta)
{
    if (delta <= 0)
        return;

    log("list(" + numItems + "): ");
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        list.add(i);
    }

    for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i=i+delta)
    {
        int max = Math.min(list.size(), i + delta);
        List<Integer> subList = list.subList(i, max);
        log("list(" + numItems + "," + delta + "): " + subList);
    }
}

public static void log(String msg) 
{
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```